# How do I run a function on a timer with a option to stop it on Python?

Tags: python, python-3.7

I am working on a Python project and I have an area in the project where I need to have a loop timer as I need the code checked, say every 5 minutes, to see if the data in the database has changed and then alert the user. Now I can do most of it with `if` statements etc, but the timer part I have no idea on how to do it.

```
remind = (input('Would you like me to remind you of the status of your flight? yes/no: '))
if remind == 'yes':
    # some how start a loop to check the database for update and give open to exit
    print('Loop to check database')
elif remind == 'no':
    print('Thank you for using FLIGHT CHECK')
    quit()
```

So the basic logic of steps I would need to take are:

```
if remind = yes
    check mysql table status
    bunch of if statement
    will also give option to stop alert
if remind = no
    end
```

Comment: What are you using to check the flight status? https?

Answer (score 0):

You can use time, and a while loop which watches a variable for true/false.

```
import time

run = True

while run: 
    remind = (input('Would you like me to remind you of the status of your flight? yes/no: '))

    if remind.lower() == 'yes':
        print('database loop')

        # Sleep for 300 seconds
        time.sleep(300) 
    elif remind.lower() == 'no':
        run = False
```

This will loop, every 5 minutes until a user answers `no` at which point it sets `run = False` and ends the while loop.

```
Would you like me to remind you of the status of your flight? yes/no: yes
database loop
Would you like me to remind you of the status of your flight? yes/no: no
>>>
```